# django widget tweaks form control not action

Tags: python, html, django, rendering, django-widget-tweaks

when Making django board, I met the problem.

django version is 3.

I wanted form like this. but my code can't alert me  "This field is required"

[image]

But widget tweaks form-control wasn't working.

[image]

which part is problem?

My code is like this

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load widget_tweaks %}

{% block title %}Start a New Topic{% endblock %}

{% block breadcrumb %}
  <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Boards</a></li>
  <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{% url 'board_topics' board.pk %}">{{ board.name }}</a></li>
  <li class="breadcrumb-item active">New topic</li>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <form method="post" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}

    {% for field in form %}
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ field.label_tag }}

                {% if form.is_bound %}
        {% if field.errors %}

          {% render_field field class="form-control is-invalid" %}
          {% for error in field.errors %}
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              {{ error }}
            </div>
          {% endfor %}

        {% else %}
          {% render_field field class="form-control is-valid" %}
        {% endif %}
      {% else %}
        {% render_field field class="form-control" %}
      {% endif %}

      {% if field.help_text %}
        <small class="form-text text-muted">
          {{ field.help_text }}
        </small>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
  {% endfor %}

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Post</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using bootstrap or django crispy forms in your form.

Answer (score 1):

just change your code to blow with proper indent

````
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% block title %}Start a New Topic{% endblock %}
{% block breadcrumb %}
  <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Boards</a></li>
  <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{% url 'board_topics' board.pk %}">{{ board.name }}</a></li>
  <li class="breadcrumb-item active">New topic</li>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<form method="post" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}

    {% for field in form %}
      <div class="form-group">
        {{ field.label_tag }}

        {% if form.is_bound %}
          {% if field.errors %}

            {% render_field field class="form-control is-invalid" %}
            {% for error in field.errors %}
              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                {{ error }}
              </div>
            {% endfor %}

          {% else %}
            {% render_field field class="form-control is-valid" %}
          {% endif %}
        {% else %}
          {% render_field field class="form-control" %}
        {% endif %}

        {% if field.help_text %}
          <small class="form-text text-muted">
            {{ field.help_text }}
          </small>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    {% endfor %}

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Post</button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}```
````